# Remove columns from data frame with hashing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, merge, multiple-columns

Given two pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(file1, names=['col1','col2','col3'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2, names=['col1','col2','col3'])
```

I'd like to remove all the rows in df2 where the values of either `col1` or `col2` (or both) do not exist in df1.

Doing the following:

```
df2 = df2[(df2['col1'] in set(df1['col1'])) & (df2['col2'] in set(df1['col2']))]
```

yields:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df2 = df2[(df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])) & (df2['col2'].isin(df1['col2']))]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,3],
                    'col2':[4,5,6,2],
                    'col3':[7,8,9,5]})

print (df1)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9
3     3     2     5

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,5],
                    'col2':[4,7,4,1],
                    'col3':[7,8,9,1]})

print (df2)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
1     2     7     8
2     3     4     9
3     5     1     1

df2 = df2[(df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])) & (df2['col2'].isin(df1['col2'].unique()))]
print (df2)
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
2     3     4     9
```

Another solution is [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), because inner join (`how='inner'`) is by default, but it works only for values with same position in both `DataFrames`:

```
print (pd.merge(df1, df2))
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     4     7
```